# How does an `if-in` evaluate to true? (only in chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Debugging someone else's code, found this,

[image]

How does an `if-in` evaluate to true? Happens only in chrome though, IE evaluates to false

Comment: That is a check if files exists in fileInput. Like `if(exists(fileInput.files))` This is not available in IE because fileInput is included since IE10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It evaluates `true` because the `fileInput` DOM element has a `files` property on Chrome. It's part of the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). It's `false` on IE because [they only added the File API to IE in IE10](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi). I'm guessing you must be using IE9 or earlier.

That's what the `in` operator does: Checks to see if an object has a property with the given name, either its own property or one it inherits from its prototype object.

Here's a straight JavaScript example:

```
var obj = {foo: 42};
console.log('foo' in obj); // true
console.log('bar' in obj); // false
```

You see this used in feature detection a lot. For instance, if you want to know whether the browser the user is using supports using `placeholder` attributes on `input` elements, you look for the reflected property:

```
if ('placeholder' in document.createElement('input')) {
    // It supports the placeholder attribute
}
```

Comment: Ok, so how can I check for this `files` property on IE? the `in` clearly doesn't work

Comment: It does work. Old IE doesn't support file API that's why there is that test, to check for browsers that don't support it.

Comment: @badZoke: `in` works fine in IE. The version of IE you're using doesn't have the `files` property, apparently. (They only added the File API to IE in IE10, [according to caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi).)

Comment: OK, so I'm testing on IE9, there's no `files` property for the element in the `watch expressions`

Comment: @badZoke: Right. IE9 doesn't have it.

Comment: @badZoke: Workaround for ***what***? If you mean, "does IE9 provide an equivalent to the `files` property?", then no. It doesn't support the File API. Microsoft came rather late to that particular table.

Comment: yes, meant this - "does IE9 provide an equivalent to the files property?", cool.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The `in` operator can be used to test for existance of a property inside an object:

```
var obj = {
  foo: 'baz'
};

console.log('foo' in obj); // true
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in